# How to prevent dismssing an alert in a log in UI Alert View Controller when log in button is tapped?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

So I'm trying to make the user log in using UIAlertViewController. Everything is working correctly, the only thing I would like to improve is to keep the same UIAlert even when the user put a wrong email or password, because when I tap log in using a wrong email, the alert automatically dismiss. So I would like to keep the same alert with the same filled text fields. Is there a way to achieve that? Tried to use several codes I found on stack, but I got confused. Can someone help me using my code to prevent dismissing the alert?

```
@objc func loginButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("Login button has been clicked")
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Iniciar sesión como conductor", message: errorsLabel, preferredStyle: .alert)

        alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Correo"
            textField.keyboardType = .emailAddress
        }
        alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Contraseña"
            textField.isSecureTextEntry = true
        }

    let loginAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Iniciar sesión", style: .default) { (_) in
           
        let emailField = alertController.textFields![0]
    
        let passwordField = alertController.textFields![1]
        
        let emailText = emailField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        
        let passwordText = passwordField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
          
            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailText, password: passwordText) { (result, error) in

            if error != nil {
                // Here is where I want the alert to not dismiss
                self.errorsLabel = "Correo eléctrónico y/o contraseña no válidos"
            }
            else {
                let homeViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.homeViewController) as? HomeViewController
                self.view.window?.rootViewController = homeViewController
                self.view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            }
        }
    }
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancelar", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    
        alertController.addAction(loginAction)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prevent a UIAlertController from dismissing when a button in the alert is tapped. You can disable the buttons, but if a button is enabled and is tapped, the alert is taken down. If you want different behavior, create your own UIViewController and present it instead.